# React.js validate props input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass values to my component 'Form' as props

```
<Form firstName={'John'} lastName={'Doe'} enabled={1} />
```

I would like to know how to validate boolean value, when enabled with value 1 assign CSS class Active otherwise add CSS class disabled.

This is what I have tried within my react component and it hasn't worked.

```
    <span className="Disabled">{this.props.enabled ? "Active" : 'Disabled'}</span>
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you pass a boolean value ´enabled={true}´ or change the condition to ´this.props.enabled==1´

Comment: I will give it a try! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the class to change on the `<span>` you'll need to set the condition on the property `className` rather than the content of the element:

```
<span className={(this.props.enabled === 1)? "Active" : 'Disabled'}></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to use `1` then you would just need to establish a `this.props.enabled === 1` variable somewehre to hold the true and false value.

Personally I would have enabled be a boolean value of `true` or `false` as it adds unnecessary complexity to make it a number.

```
<span className={this.props.enabled === 1 ? "Active" : 'Disabled'}></span>
```